# How to get the value on select in JS

Tags: javascript, select, onchange

How can I get the value on select to change the town in order to get the weather info?
I tried adding some event listeners but cannot seem to get it working.
Where exactly do I need to add the function or the event listener to get the value? Sorry, I am trying to understand it all but I'm still not sure.

```js
const key = '';
if (key == '') document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = ('');

function weatherApp(name) {
  fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + name + '&appid=' + key)
    .then(function(resp) {
      return resp.json()
    }) // Convert data to json
    .then(function(data) {
      drawWeather(data);
    })
    .catch(function() {
      // catch any errors
    });
}

function drawWeather(d) {
  var celcius = Math.round(parseFloat(d.main.temp) - 273.15);
  var fahrenheit = Math.round(((parseFloat(d.main.temp) - 273.15) * 1.8) + 32);
  var description = d.weather[0].description;

  document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = description;
  document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = celcius + '&deg;';
  document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = d.name;

  if (description.indexOf('rain') > 0) {
    document.body.className = 'rainy';
  } else if (description.indexOf('cloud') > 0) {
    document.body.className = 'cloudy';
  } else if (description.indexOf('sunny') > 0) {
    document.body.className = 'sunny';
  } else {
    document.body.className = 'clear';
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  weatherApp("Manchester");
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="selectCountry">
  <option>Select a country</option>
  <option disabled="">_________</option>
  <option value="Kabul,AF">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Luanda,AO">Angola</option>
  <option value="Canberra,AU">Australia</option>
  <option value="Vienna,AT">Austria</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please add some more context to what you want help on.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood, you want to call the `weatherApp` function when the value on the `select` element has changed.

For this, use the [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event for the [`select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) element.
This event will fire when the [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#attr-value) for a [`select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) element has changed.

```js
const key = '';

function weatherApp(name) {
  fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + name + '&appid=' + key)
    .then(function(resp) {
      return resp.json()
    }) // Convert data to json
    .then(function(data) {
      drawWeather(data);
    })
    .catch(function() {
      // catch any errors
    });
}

const formControl = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0];

formControl.addEventListener("change", function() {
  weatherApp(formControl.value);
})

function drawWeather(d) {
  var celcius = Math.round(parseFloat(d.main.temp) - 273.15);
  var fahrenheit = Math.round(((parseFloat(d.main.temp) - 273.15) * 1.8) + 32);
  var description = d.weather[0].description;

  document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = description;
  document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = celcius + '&deg;';
  document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = d.name;

  if (description.indexOf('rain') > 0) {
    document.body.className = 'rainy';
  } else if (description.indexOf('cloud') > 0) {
    document.body.className = 'cloudy';
  } else if (description.indexOf('sunny') > 0) {
    document.body.className = 'sunny';
  } else {
    document.body.className = 'clear';
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  weatherApp("Manchester");
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="selectCountry">
  <option>Select a country</option>
  <option disabled="">_________</option>
  <option value="Kabul,AF">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Luanda,AO">Angola</option>
  <option value="Canberra,AU">Australia</option>
  <option value="Vienna,AT">Austria</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hello,Thank you very mich for your answer. You got it right but I am struggling to make it working. I changed the function at the end with this, as well as a houndred others :) but still cannot get it working :(. Am I on the right way?     select.onchange = function() {
 weatherApp(select.value("#selectCountry"))
};